# Ruby Block won't change local variable

Tags: ruby, scope, block

this code here:

```
def create_sym_matrix
  ran_arr = Array.new(5){rand(1..100)}
  ran_arr[1] = 0
  mat_arr = Array.new(5){|i|ran_arr.push(ran_arr.shift)}
  Matrix.columns(mat_arr)
end

aa = create_sym_matrix

=> Matrix[[86, 86, 86, 86, 86], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [20, 20, 20, 20, 20], 
[39, 39, 39, 39, 39], [48, 48, 48, 48, 48]]
```

Can someone explain to me why it did not rotate? I was trying to get a symmetric Matrix with zeros in the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`Array::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-c-new) explains:

> **new(size=0, default=nil)**
>   **new(array)**
>   **new(size) {|index| block }**
>   ...
>
> In the last form, an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element's index to the given block and storing the return value.

The block `{|i|ran_arr.push(ran_arr.shift)}` always returns the same value: the array stored in `ran_arr`. The new array contains 5 references to `ran_arr`. The rows of `mat_arr` contain the same values because there aren't five different rows; it's the same object linked five times.

To fix this you should return from the block a copy of `ran_arr`:

```
  mat_arr = Array.new(5){|i|ran_arr.push(ran_arr.shift).clone}
```

You will notice that it still doesn't generate a matrix with zeroes on the diagonal. To achieve this goal you need to correct the algorithm:

```
def create_sym_matrix
  ran_arr = Array.new(5){rand(1..100)}
  ran_arr[4] = 0
  mat_arr = Array.new(5){|i|ran_arr.unshift(ran_arr.pop).clone}
  Matrix.columns(mat_arr)
end
```

The output:

```
Matrix[[0, 38, 8, 48, 73], [73, 0, 38, 8, 48], [48, 73, 0, 38, 8], [8, 48, 73, 0, 38], [38, 8, 48, 73, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why the block returns the same value over and over?

Comment: Ruby objects are copied by reference. This means `a = ran_arr` doesn't duplicate the value of `ran_arr`, it only creates a new name for it.

Comment: The block changes `ran_arr` every time it runs. After 5 rotations it leaves the values of `ran_arr` in the same order they were when `ran_arr` was created.

Comment: That is quite a mess i made